# Photogrammetry or Drones program

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, orthophotography

I'm seeking a free software, online, or open source  that I can use to use perform my Photogrammetry on aerial photography. The following I am looking for are:

- Must be on Windows 10.
- Must be free. No payment.
- Can handle big file size.
- stable.
- Must be a good or an Excellent reviews from end-users.
- Must be able to open any type of photo extension that can read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenDroneMap](https://www.opendronemap.org/) advertises itself as: "A command line toolkit to process aerial images. Since it’s creation in 2014, it has become the de-facto standard of open source drone image processing.".

Favorable Write-ups:

- ExpoUAV - "[OpenDroneMap: a Toolkit for Processing Aerial Drone Imagery](https://www.expouav.com/news/latest/opendronemap-toolkit-processing-aerial-drone-imagery/)"
- DroneZon - "[10 Best Photogrammetry Software For 3D Mapping Using Drones](https://www.dronezon.com/learn-about-drones-quadcopters/drone-3d-mapping-photogrammetry-software-for-survey-gis-models/)".
- GIS.SE - "[Drone aerial imagery to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202576/drone-aerial-imagery-to-qgis)" (mentioned in comments and answers). See [Tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opendronemap).
- Conference Paper - "[Evaluation of OpenDroneMap Toolkit for Geodetic Grade Aerial Drone Mapping - Case Study](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318276585_EVALUATION_OF_OPEN_DRONE_MAP_TOOLKIT_FOR_GEODETIC_GRADE_AERIAL_DRONE_MAPPING_-_CASE_STUDY)".

Apparently [MapsMadeEasy](https://www.mapsmadeeasy.com/pricing) is better, and they credit you with enough to map 200 acres (after which you pay, if you call that ***free***). The authors of OpenDroneMap have great credentials and funding but there's a learning curve.